# Histogram with custom y frequency python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am trying to plot the following data

```
+-----------+------+------+
| Duration  | Code | Seq. |
+-----------+------+------+
|    116.15 |   65 |    1 |
|    120.45 |   65 |    1 |
|    118.92 |   65 |    1 |
|      7.02 |   66 |    1 |
|     73.93 |   66 |    2 |
|    117.53 |   66 |    1 |
|       4.4 |   66 |    2 |
|    111.03 |   66 |    1 |
|      4.35 |   66 |    1 |
+-----------+------+------+
```

I have my code as:

```
x1 = df.loc[df.Code==65, 'Duration']
x2 = df.loc[df.Code==66, 'Duration']
kwargs = dict(alpha=0.5, bins=10)
plt.hist(x1, **kwargs, color='k', label='Code 65')
plt.hist(x2, **kwargs, color='g', label='Code 66')
```

What I ideally want on the y axis is the number of `Seq`.corresponding to different `Durations`on x axis. But now, I only get the count of the `Durations`on y. How do I correct this?

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Do you want this: `df.groupby('Code').plot(y='Seq.', x='Duration', kind='bar', subplots=True)`? You said `hist` so probably not. what's your expected output.

Comment: I don't think the above helps. I expect to see the histogram and count the # of Seq. at each Duration (for different Codes)

Answer (score 0):

You might bin the 'x' values using pandas and then use a bar chart instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration':[116.15, 120.45,118.92,7.02,73.93, 117.53, 4.4, 111.03, 4.35]})
df['Code'] = [65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66]
df['Seq.'] = [1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1]
df

   Duration  Code  Seq.
0    116.15    65     1
1    120.45    65     1
2    118.92    65     1
3      7.02    66     1
4     73.93    66     2
5    117.53    66     1
6      4.40    66     2
7    111.03    66     1
8      4.35    66     1

df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['Duration'],10, labels=False)
df

   Duration  Code  Seq.  bin
0    116.15    65     1    9
1    120.45    65     1    9
2    118.92    65     1    9
3      7.02    66     1    0
4     73.93    66     2    5
5    117.53    66     1    9
6      4.40    66     2    0
7    111.03    66     1    9
8      4.35    66     1    0
x1 = df.loc[df.Code==65, 'bin']
x2 = df.loc[df.Code==66, 'bin']
y1 = df.loc[df.Code==65, 'Seq.']
y2 = df.loc[df.Code==66, 'Seq.']

plt.bar(x1, y1)
plt.bar(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I run the df['bin'] line, it gives all nan's in the bin column.

Comment: I've updated the code to show the entire output, so if you're data is different than what you provided the cut command may need to be tweaked.  Also, this approach add up the Seq values in each bin.  If instead you want to know how many of the Seq. values are 1 versus 2, then you probably need a different visual cause then you are asking for three dimensions (count of Seq. by duration(bin) + Seq. #)